# Localization of custom label to be used in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-experience, customlabel, localization

//edit 1 - addition of 2 images

[image: user locale settings]
[image: custom label view]
Also note that text within the images in communities home page is getting converted but not the custom label in the lightning form contained in the community.

//edit 1 end

I have a requirement to show custom label in lightning component based on user's locale settings in SFDC.

When I open this form in community as that user(whose locale, language is changed to Japaneese) the label is still in English

Following is code in lightning component:-

```
   <div class="slds-col--padded-medium  field-wrapper">
            <lightning:input required="true" type="text" name="input1" aura:id="CompanyNameEnglish"
                             label="{!$Label.c.Company_name}"  value="{!v.account.Name}" disabled="true"
                             messageWhenValueMissing="Please enter the value." />
            <span>
                <small  style="font-size: 8pt;color: #6b6d70;padding-left: 12px;" class="text-muted">
                    Please provide full legal name of your company
                </small>
            </span>
        </div>
```

In translations of custom label, translations in Japaneese and chineese are present. Label is being fetched correctly, but in english. Need a way to show as per user's locale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding languages to community was the solution after enabling languages in translation workbench and translations in requisite custom labels.